# Put quotes around item after the 10th comma

Tags: awk

I used to have an awk command that worked well in putting quotes around the last item (after the 10th comma) in my output files, so that when I open them as a CSV file the last item doesn't get split up because of its extra commas. However, for some reason, the awk command is broken (I never came up with it someone helped me create it) and it returns a file with many empty lines or deleted data.

Here is a sample of my initial output file:

```
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,Plantago lanceolata ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,Brassica sp. 4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial
```

And here is what I want my output file to look like - it just has quotes around the last item which is the full name of the species and its sequencing info.

```
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp. 4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

Ideally, I would like a way to split the species name from the rest of the name too if possible so the output would be:

```
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum", "voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"   
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum", "voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"        
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata", ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"     
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.", "4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

The awk command I've used before that seemed to work fine before, but now my output comes out like this:

```
for file in *.txt; do awk '{ match($0,/((\S+\s+){10})(.*)/,a); gsub(/\s+/,",",a[1]); gsub(/"/,"&&",a[3]); print a[1] "\"" a[3] "\"" }' $file > ${file%%.txt}_cleanedup.txt; done
```

Output (It's not putting quotes around the proper part, should be everything after the 10th comma). Also, the empty quotes just mean the data was for some reason deleted:

```
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,Gymnanthemum,amygdalinum,voucher,PCG/UNN/030-52,ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate,carboxylase/oxygenase,large,subunit,(rbcL),gene,,"partial cds; chloroplast"

e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,Gymnanthemum,amygdalinum,voucher,PCG/UNN/030-52,ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate,carboxylase/oxygenase,large,subunit,(rbcL),gene,,"partial cds; chloroplast"

""

023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,Brassica,sp.,4,KS-2019,ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate,carboxylase/oxygenase,(rbcL),pseudogene,,partial,sequence;,"mitochondrial"
```

Comment: Your posted code (`match($0,/((\S+\s+){10})...`) is designed to work on space-separated (`\s`) input, not comma-separated (`,`) input so it wouldn't have worked fine before on input that looks like the input in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /^([^,]*,){10}/) {
   print substr($0, 1, RLENGTH) "\"" substr($0, RLENGTH+1) "\""
}' file

e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp. 4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

Comment: I know it's been a while on this but I am coming back after a long leave from work and was reworking some old data. This works great but I was wondering how to split the last column with species name and the rest of the voucher name? So instead of just adding quotes around all of the info in the last column, is there a way to also separate the first two words (genus and species) from the remaining info? Thanks so much for your help. I'm not that great with awk at all so I'm having a hard time adjusting this script to add quotes without my lines just getting deleted.

Comment: Hello @KatherineChau, yes it is pretty old answer. Can you please post a new question with this additional requirement and example input/output data.

Comment: I have done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795140/separate-terms-in-last-column-with-quotes

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` you could use `match` with array concept to get this achieved.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,/^(([^,]*,){10})(.*)$/,arr){
  print arr[1] s1 arr[3] s1
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

don't waste time counting the commas - simply leverage the fact there aren't existing double quotes within this `CSV`, then let `FS + ORS` handle it for you ::

> ```
> mawk '$11 = "\"" $11' FS=, OFS=, ORS='"\n'
> ```