# Separate terms in last column with quotes?

Tags: awk

Here is a sample of my initial output file:

```
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,Gymnanthemum amygdalinum voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,Plantago lanceolata ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,Brassica sp. 4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial
```

Ideally, I would like my output to split the species name from the rest of the voucher name so the output would be:

```
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"   
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"        
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata","ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"     
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

The awk command I have that works in just adding quotes around the last column is:

```
mawk '$2 = "\"" $2' FS=, OFS=, ORS='"\n'
```

But I don't know how to change this in order to split the first two terms (genus and species name) with quotes. I will need to do this so that I can manipulate the data further using species name.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Sorry for miscommunication - species name is in the last column (should be column 11) and it would be the first TWO terms which are genus and species. Anything following that is just extra metadata/voucher info which isn't necessary but I want to keep it anyways.

So for example in the last line of the example data, after the 10th column which is a number, we have the following term:

```
Brassica sp. 4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial
```

And from this, "Brassica sp." should be it's own term in double quotes, and everything else afterwards is also in double quotes and would become the 12th column, and this would contain semi colons, colons etc, because that is unfortunately how people input the metadata for this.

It should look like:

```
"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

And then the FULL line should be:

```
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

Comment: Need more details. Which column number is species name. Are you trying to put quotes around some specific column?

Comment: you should assume that many of us do not know what you mean by `species` and `rest of voucher name` so we're left guessing at what part of the data is to be processed; I'm ***guessing*** what you want is something like: *split the last comma-delimited field into 2 new comma-delimited fields, where the 1st new field consists of the first two whitespace-delimited strings and the 2nd new field consists of the rest of the line, with both of the two new fields wrapped in double quotes*; consider updating the question with more details as to how we're to *split the species name*

Comment: hmmmm, looking at the data more closely ... looks like the 'last field' actually contains a couple commas, so we've got commas as delimiters and data ???

Comment: please review your expected output; looks like the 3rd line is missing a leading `"` for the last field

Comment: Do you REALLY want a blank after the `,` in `"Brassica sp.", "4 KS-2019..."`. etc. as shown in your expected output?

Comment: No the blank is not necessary. I will remove those blanks. Just wanted the terms separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you provide clarity on the questions being asked below your questions.

Based on your previous question(s) and my interpretation I think this awk should do what you want:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /^([^,]*,){10}/) {
   p = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)
   s = substr($0, RLENGTH+1)
   if (match(s, /^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+/)) {
      species = substr(s, 1, RLENGTH)
      voucher = substr(s, RLENGTH+1)
      sub(/^ +/, "", voucher)
      print p "\"" species "\",\"" voucher "\""
   }
}' file

e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata","ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed that supports `-E` for Extended regexps, e.g. GNU and BSD seds:

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){10})([^ ]+ [^ ]+) +(.*)/\1"\3","\4"/' file
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata","ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

or the same using an awk that supports `gensub()`, e.g. GNU and mawk2 awks:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(([^,]*,){10})([^ ]+ [^ ]+) +(.*)/,"\\1\"\\3\",\"\\4\"",1)}' file
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata","ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```

or using a POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{10\}\)\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) *\(.*\)/\1"\3","\4"/' file
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
e7479580f6f3be15b5632f64f9de8df7,gi|1858620278|gb|MN628024.1|,132,541,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,82755,"Gymnanthemum amygdalinum","voucher PCG/UNN/030-52 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcL) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
b875a20e3a4876aba15b0edf8973a3f4,gi|1832942633|gb|MN431198.1|,132,573,100,132,100.000,2.02e-60,244,39414,"Plantago lanceolata","ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase large subunit (rbcl) gene, partial cds; chloroplast"
023abf2ebf1c94fe890dfd1517a828c5,gi|1562068410|gb|MH569150.1|,132,715,98,129,100.000,9.41e-59,239,2508311,"Brassica sp.","4 KS-2019 ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase/oxygenase (rbcL) pseudogene, partial sequence; mitochondrial"
```